# OnDraw() is not fired, nothing is drawn in surfaceView - Android

Tags: android, surfaceview, ondraw

HI! I have a surfaceView inside a horizontal scrollview that I want to fill with images with a onDraw() call. However, nothing is drawn. 
I have a class in which the drawing is done from the thread CanvasThread.

```
public class PanelChart extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
private CanvasThread canvasthread ;
public PanelChart(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
getHolder().addCallback(this);
canvasthread = new CanvasThread(getHolder(), this);
setFocusable(true);
```

I have tried to change the

```
`synchronized (_surfaceHolder) {
                      _panel.postInvalidate();
                    }`
```

to 
`synchronized (_surfaceHolder) {
                          _panel.postInvalidate();
                        }`

I have also tried to add the call setWillNotDraw(false) without luck:

```
 @Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    canvasthread.setRunning(true);
    canvasthread.start();
   setWillNotDraw(false);
```

This seems to be a common issue, but none of the solutions I have come across have worked for me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

postInvalidate will not call onDraw with surfaceView. You need to unlock canvas, draw things and then lock canvas. Here is an example of a thread for surfaceView:

```
    class CanvasThread extends Thread {
        private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
        private PanelChart panel;
        private boolean run = false;

        public CanvasThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, PanelChart panel) {
            this.surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
            this.panel = panel;
        }

        public void setRunning(boolean run) {
            this.run = run;
        }

        public SurfaceHolder getSurfaceHolder() {
            return surfaceHolder;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Canvas c;
            while (run) {
                c = null;

                //limit the frame rate to maximum 60 frames per second (16 miliseconds)
                timeNow = System.currentTimeMillis();
                timeDelta = timeNow - timePrevFrame;
                if ( timeDelta < 16){
                    try{
                        Thread.sleep(16 - timeDelta);
                    }catch(InterruptedException e){

                    }
                }
                timePrevFrame = System.currentTimeMillis();

                try {
                    c = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
                    synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
                        panel.onDraw(c); //draw canvas 
                        computePhysics(); //calculate next frame
                    }
                } finally {
                    if (c != null) {
                        surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);  //show canvas
                    }
                }//try finally
              } //while
        }//run
    }//thread
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work either. Do you mean that the key is to start the thread, which calls OnDraw, then sleep the thread and then unlock it? So the problem should be in the thread?

Comment: Yes, start the thread when you need it animated. I am not sure if this would work in a scroll view, but it works well when SurfaceView is the only view. ScrollView is redrawing its views when you scroll it and that may interfear with SurfaceView drawing... so you need to experiment.

Comment: You were right, it was the horizontal scrollview I had placed the surfaceview inside that was messing with me. THanks Lumis!