# bitmap.eraseColor(COLOR.TRANSPARENT) not working on surfaceview

Tags: java, android

I have a surfaceview in my layout, which i draw a bitmap to.
I make the surfaceview transparent by calling this code :

// framebuffer is a Bitmap

```
    setZOrderOnTop(true);
    this.framebuffer = framebuffer;        
    this.holder = getHolder();        
    this.holder.setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);
```

Now i want to clear the screen by using this :

```
    framebuffer.eraseColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

But it does not work.
If i replace Color.TRANSPARENT with any other color it does paint the whole surface with that color i.e.

```
    framebuffer.eraseColor(Color.WHITE);
```

Anyone have any ideas ? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Answering my own question.

For some reason i had to call both

              canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
              this.framebuffer.eraseColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

But it was still flickering.

The flickering was due to the double buffering behaviour of the surfaceview.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847323/android-surfaceview-canvas-flickering-after-trying-to-clear-it

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question.

For some reason i had to call both

```
                canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
                this.framebuffer.eraseColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

But it was still flickering.

[Android SurfaceView/Canvas flickering after trying to clear it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847323/android-surfaceview-canvas-flickering-after-trying-to-clear-it)