# How to freeze the last frame of an animation in a SurfaceView?

Tags: java, android, performance, android-canvas, android-animation

I'm drawing on a SurfaceView using a thread that has the following calssic run() method:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while (mRun) {
        Canvas canvas = null;
        synchronized (mSurfaceHolder) {
                try {
                    canvas = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                    update();
                    doDraw(canvas);
                } finally {
                    if (canvas != null) {
                        mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

I wanted to save some work if the next frames that are about to be drawn from that moment on, are exactly the same as the previous one, so I skipped the onDraw, but than I got [flickering issues due to the double buffering mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847323/android-surfaceview-canvas-flickering-after-trying-to-clear-it).
Then I went on and did something like this:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while (mRun) {
        Canvas canvas = null;
        synchronized (mSurfaceHolder) {
            if (mIsAnimating) {          // <---- Look ma! A flag!!!
                try {
                    canvas = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                    update();
                    doDraw(canvas);
                } finally {
                    if (canvas != null) {
                        mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I turn off the mIsAnimating flag, thus stopping my run loop from locking the canvas and drawing on it, everything worked like a charm - I did some animation and after it was finished, I could freeze the drawing cycle and keep the animation's last frame on screen.

But then I had to go and see the following from [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.html#lockCanvas%28%29):

> The content of the Surface is never preserved between unlockCanvas()
>   and lockCanvas(), for this reason, every pixel within the Surface area
>   must be written. The only exception to this rule is when a dirty
>   rectangle is specified, in which case, non-dirty pixels will be
>   preserved.

So... how come my code works?

Comment: Probably because your surface view doesn't get invalidated, meaning it doesn't try to redraw anything (so it keeps a cached bitmap of the view). If the view gets re-laid out or invalidated, you'd probably need to redraw it.

Comment: You mean that as long as I don't change my surface view's layout, it won't get invalidated? If I'll override the view's invalidation methods and raise the mIsAnimating flag to true, the view will be redrawn OK?

Comment: Isn't there a method to save / get / push the current canvas / view / surface content ? (Sorry to be vague - have to look into this in a few days myself.)

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a good one. The `SurfaceView` is a strange animal.

First, `View`s, in general, don't use cached drawing by default (as far as I know, that is still true), and `SurfaceView` doesn't do anything to enable it. So I'm reasonably sure there's no caching going on.

What the `SurfaceView` *is* doing is cutting a hole in the view hierarchy's `Window` so that you can see another `Window` or something drawn directly on the frame buffer behind it. Android has added a non-existent Porter-Duff mode into their `PorterDuff.Mode` enum to accomplish this weird behavior. Because of this, the normal drawing rules don't apply to `SurfaceView`. Invalidating or requesting a layout simply cuts the hole again. The view hierarchy doesn't know or care anything about what's actually drawn in that area of the screen, so unless you specifically draw on it some other way (e.g., using the `SurfaceHolder` to procure a `Canvas` for that same area on a separate `Window`), there's a reasonable chance it just sits there untouched.

So what I really think is happening is that Android simply isn't redrawing that portion of the frame buffer. What was drawn there from the `Surface` stays there while the rest of the view hierarchy is drawn around it. The resources of the `Surface` very well could be deallocated and you would never know.

I'm curious what happens if you switch to a different `Activity` or the home screen and come back? My guess is that your last frame will no longer be there. If it is, then `SurfaceView` is even stranger than I am aware...

Edit: Just a brief note... a `Window` is basically a `Surface` with a little extra functionality. My habit of using the term `Window` interchangeably with `Surface` is because a `Surface` is basically `ANativeWindow` on the native side of things.

Comment: Thanks Dave. I'm using the SurfaceView using a Service and adding it using WindowManager.addView(). If I remove the SurfaceView by WindowManager.removeView(), waiting 2 seconds and re-adding the SurfaceView, it still has the freeze frame... I'm happy with that, but don't know why it works. I found lots of information about why you should redraw everytime, but didn't find anything about why my way works.

Comment: Also, I read about it and I don't get the "cutting a hole" thing - if Android wants something to be visible behind the SurfaceView, the SurfaceFlinger should blend the transparent pixels with the other surfaces. Why does it need to punch a hole?

Comment: In Android, a `Window` is basically a drawing layer. The view hierarchy was originally intended to always be the bottom `Window` (layer) with other things blended on top as overlays. Its first rendering step is to draw a completely opaque black background. Nothing can be blended behind it. Then they realized there was a problem. Developers sometimes need drawing surfaces that aren't encumbered with the mechanics of the view hierarchy, and ideally aren't pulled through the JNI layer (which isn't a speedy process at all). Enter `SurfaceView`.

Comment: When it gets to a `SurfaceView`, pixels are erased with `PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR`. Any `View`s that had drawn in that area disappear, along with the opaque black background. `Window`s underneath are now visible. Now there is a method for the most demanding image stream producers (`MediaPlayer`, native code, etc.) to draw without being bothered with the view hierarchy, but still be rendered in a way that seems as if they are a part of the view hierarchy. Like I said, it's a bit strange, but a reasonable solution in the end.

Comment: Also, if your frame is being redrawn the resources aren't being deallocated. I suppose "never preserved" doesn't mean "always eliminated", but I can't explain that part off the top of my head.

My initial thought is that there is a weak (or maybe soft) reference on the backing bitmap and the GC hasn't decided it's ok to remove it yet. When I get a few minutes to look at the source I will do so.

Comment: After perusing the source a bit, it only tries to release `Surface` resources when the layout changes. In your case, you are seeing the resource persist through a layout change, though, which is odd to say the least. I have an idea or two as to why, but I would need access to more of your code and/or LogCat output to understand it more completely. If you would like my help in exploring further, feel free to pm me.

Comment: Oops, [you can't](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user). My email should show on my profile, though.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37036/discussion-between-ron-tesler-and-dave)

Answer (score 1):

I think that one of two things are happening, first (very unlikely) you might be accidentally drawing the last frame of the animation repeatedly, IF NOT, then it means that your SurfaceView is not being invalidated by any change on the view hence keeping cached the last buffer of pixels showed, in order to test it, set a button on the screen and when the SurfaceView gets "frozen" tap on button and make the button itself gone, so you will force a redraw over all the elements on the screen, if the animation dissapears mean that it was actually being cached...

Regards!

Comment: I made sure that I'm not redrawing the last animation frame, and I tested what happens after invalidation, and the frame is still frozen as wanted.
Still don't get it...

Answer (score 0):

You redraw only when your application surface changes. That works well. But - and that's what the Android document is refering to - any other App, Service, Toast or whatever can overwrite parts of your surface for a while. Take a `Toast` from a `Service` as example. Your App and your `SurfaceView` must update that part of the screen when the Toast disappears. But in your code you do not update as long as your flag is not set.

Comment: I created a test - I showed a toast while the animation was running and the toast disappeared after the animation froze. Everything looks OK although I didn't update that part of the screen after the toast was gone.

Comment: @Ron Tesler. Did you really change the screen behind the Toast while the Toast was displayed? Good code with nice timing! The question is, why the Android doc writes this warning but you cannot create a test case where this goes wrong. I've seen some examples in the doc where Android is quite defensive, means they do not know what each and every device does and describe therefore the minimum possible. With your code, who knows what happen on different devices? The only shame is, that we do not yet have found 'the right way'.

Comment: Yes, it was pretty easy - I displayed a toast on the start on a very short animation. The animation freeze its last frame and the toast disappeared later on. I was wondering - If I want my thread to sleep for 16ms, do I need to make it sleep while the canvas is locked, so it will be preserved? Making it sleep after the canvas is unlocked is almost the same as my way of doing things...