# Surface Created never called and so the thread never runs?

Tags: android, multithreading, surfaceview

I have been struggling with this issue since a long time.I am a newbie to android. I have done all the homework and gone through all the topics related to my issues but it did not help.

My app code is based on lunar lander with modifications. I have got a splash screen which then displays a menu screen which launches my main activity.

In my App, I have a claSS Game which I have declared in the main.xml as follows:-

I am pasting the portion of the xml file:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/desert"
        android:clipToPadding="true">

     <com.example.android.Game
      android:id="@+id/Game"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

I am trying to inflate this activity from my app's MainActivity as follows:-

Unlike lunar lander my thread is seperate class from the  Main activity.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mGame = (Game) findViewById(R.id.Game);
        mGameThread = mGame.getThread();
```

I have created a thread the definition of which is in a seperate file but  but which is declared as part of Game class..

The problem I am facing is that the surfacecreated for my Game class is never called.So the thread never runs.

Below I am pasting the Game Class

```
public class Game extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

     private int mX;
     private int mY;
     private int mSpeedX;
     private int mSpeedY;
     private Bitmap mBitmap;

     private GameThread thread;

     public static Context mContext;

     private TextView mStatusText;

     private boolean mSurfaceExists;

     public Game(Context context)
     {
         super(context);
           SurfaceHolder holder = getHolder();
         holder.addCallback(this);  

         // create thread only; it's started in surfaceCreated()
         Log.w(this.getClass().getName(),"Before thread create");
         thread = new GameThread(holder, context, new Handler() {

             @Override
             public void handleMessage(Message m) {
                 Log.w(this.getClass().getName(),"In Handle message");
                  mStatusText.setVisibility(m.getData().getInt("viz"));
                    mStatusText.setText(m.getData().getString("text"));
                }


         });

         setFocusable(true); // make sure we get key events

     }

     public Game(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
         super(context, attrs, defStyle);
         SurfaceHolder holder = getHolder();
         holder.addCallback(this);  

         // create thread only; it's started in surfaceCreated()
         Log.w(this.getClass().getName(),"Before thread create");
         thread = new GameThread(holder, context, new Handler() {

             @Override
             public void handleMessage(Message m) {
                 Log.w(this.getClass().getName(),"In Handle message");
                  mStatusText.setVisibility(m.getData().getInt("viz"));
                    mStatusText.setText(m.getData().getString("text"));
                }


         });

         setFocusable(true); // make sure we get key events

     }

     public Game(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
         super(context, attrs);
         // register our interest in hearing about changes to our surface
         SurfaceHolder holder = getHolder();
         holder.addCallback(this);  

         // create thread only; it's started in surfaceCreated()
         Log.w(this.getClass().getName(),"Before thread create");
         thread = new GameThread(holder, context, new Handler() {

             @Override
             public void handleMessage(Message m) {
                 Log.w(this.getClass().getName(),"In Handle message");
                  mStatusText.setVisibility(m.getData().getInt("viz"));
                    mStatusText.setText(m.getData().getString("text"));
                }


         });

         setFocusable(true); // make sure we get key events

     }


     /**
         * Fetches the animation thread corresponding to this LunarView.
         * 
         * @return the animation thread
         */
        public GameThread getThread() {
            return thread;
        }



        /**
         * Standard window-focus override. Notice focus lost so we can pause on
         * focus lost. e.g. user switches to take a call.
         */
        @Override
        public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasWindowFocus) {
            if (!hasWindowFocus) thread.pause();
        }

        /**
         * Installs a pointer to the text view used for messages.
         */
        public void setTextView(TextView textView) {
            mStatusText = textView;
        }

     public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.w(this.getClass().getName(),":In surface changed");
         thread.setSurfaceSize(width, height);
        }
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            // start the thread here so that we don't busy-wait in run()
            // waiting for the surface to be created
            mSurfaceExists = false;

            Log.w(this.getClass().getName(),"In Surface create");
            Log.w(this.getClass().getName(),":Before starting thread at create");
            thread.setRunning(true);
            thread.start();
        }

          /*
         * Callback invoked when the Surface has been destroyed and must no longer
         * be touched. WARNING: after this method returns, the Surface/Canvas must
         * never be touched again!
         */

        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             // we have to tell thread to shut down & wait for it to finish, or else
            // it might touch the Surface after we return and explode
            boolean retry = true;
            mSurfaceExists = false;

            Log.w(this.getClass().getName(),"In Surface destroy");
            thread.setRunning(false);
            while (retry) {
                try {
                    thread.join();
                    retry = false;
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }



        }
```

Comment: After struggling a lot, I read from one of the stackoverflow's resolved question that the surface view does not works inside a horizontel scroll view!!! Here is the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6219473/ondraw-is-not-fired-nothing-is-drawn-in-surfaceview-android).Can anyone suggest me alternate design approach as I do require horizontal scroll view